# Do any generic OBD tools provide re-keying OBD Key?

Tags: obd-ii, key

It seems the rekeying mechanisms use OBD II. Here is an [example of one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NVCLPCG). Do any generic OBD II Diagnostic and Key Code Clearing tools support this rekeying functionality via OBD Key? Preferably one with Linux support?

Comment: Why did you close this? Asking if a tool has been invtened yet is hardly "price shopping"?